# Cannot load the image using json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (data[i].ProductId && data[i].Name && data[i].ShortDescription && data[i].MediumImage && data[i].Price && data[i].IconImage) {

    alert(data)

    //var date = new Date(parseInt(data[i].date.substr(6)));
    var Photoq = "../Images/HomeImages/" + data[i].MediumImage;

    alert(Photoq);

    //<img id="imgAd" src="/Images/HomeImages/1.jpg" width="181px" height="215px" alt="img">
    var Photo = "<img id='imgAd' src='" + Photoq + "' width='181px' height='215px' alt='img'/>";

    alert(Photo);

    txt += '<tr><td><div id ="result1" ><div>' + Photo + '</div> <div ><div>' + data[i].ProductId + "</br> Name- " + data[i].Name + "</br> Description " + data[i].ShortDescription + ", </br>" + data[i].Price + "</br>";
  }
}

if (txt != "") {
  $("#table").append(txt);
}
```

I am getting the name of the image in the alert but the image is not rendering. I used the same procedure for another project and it worked there. Don't know why its not working here.

Comment: What is rendered out? Post that please.

Comment: img is written and the empty image icon is being displayed

Comment: Check the network tab in developer tools for any 404's then. I suspect the path is bad.

Comment: I am getting all the details but the image is not rendering

Comment: As I said, check the path is correct.

Comment: Yeah path was bad. its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your src should be:

```
var Photoq = "/Images/HomeImages/" + data[i].MediumImage;
```

`/Images/HomeImages/..` is an absolute path. This means the resource is searched starting from the server's root.
Using `/file.jpg` means you are searching directly in the server's root.

When you are not using a leading slash it means you have a relative path. So starting from current directory in the file system you are following the path. `../` means you are looking in the parent directory.

Comment: Hey ! it worked . Thanks a lot. why sometimes we have to put "../" ?